# Connecting Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word with DocumentOpenXml

Tags: c#, openxml, word-interop

I have to copy selected text from activedocument to new file (at the end of target file). Both (source and target) are docx files. The source file is opened in Word and the user is working with it.

I would like to copy the selection without opening the target file as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document and copy-paste (for performance reasons).
I don't know how to change the "Selection" in open document to xml understandable by DocumentOpenXml and how to inject this xml into target file.

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using Range = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range;


public void RangeToNewDocument(string documentPath, Range range)
{

    string selectedXML = range.WordOpenXML; //??????????
    using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(documentPath, true))
    {
        Body body = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;

        //body.Append(selectedXML); ??????

        doc.SaveAs(documentPath + ".RangeToNewDocumentTest.docx");
    }
}
```

Many example codes are for "How to add something" but there are new objects (as 'Runs' or all 'Paragraphs') but I couldn't find anything about an existing object.
The only link I found is:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-copy-the-contents-of-an-open-xml-package-part-to-a-document-part-in-a-dif

but there replace one ThemePart with another and I have no idea how to adjust it for me.

Comment: How familiar are you with Open XML and the Open XML SDK (`DocumentFormat.OpenXml`)? I'm asking because your approach may be too complex if (a) what you need to copy can be complex and (b) you are not familiar enough with Open XML. For example, are you familiar with the specifics of the Open XML markup returned by the `WordOpenXML` property?

Comment: Even if it is unknown to me now, I would like to learn.

I don't know what the user selects. There will certainly be hyperlinks in the content, but there should be no footnotes or endnotes.

Now, I put a tab on the range, open the file, insert a file (range with a tab) and close the file. But it takes a noticeably long time. Both files are based on the same template (.dotm) - same set of styles.

Comment: If you want to learn, have a look at the [Open XML SDK](https://github.com/dotnet/Open-XML-SDK). You'll also find links to other repositories, such as the Open XML PowerTools, where you'll find many examples.